# I'm not able to create a databbase in SQLite-net

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, .net-standard

```
public static class DatabaseTools
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Static properties for SQLDB connection
    /// </summary>
    public static string DataSource = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "MyData.db");
    public static SQLiteConnectionString db = new SQLiteConnectionString(DataSource, false);
    public static SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(db);
    
    public static void CreateDB()
    {  
        conn.CreateTable<Task>();
    }
    public static List<Task> GetTasks()
    {
        var result = conn.Table<Task>().OrderBy(t => t.Id).ToList();
        return result;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This method adds a single Task to the DB 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"> Refers to the Task.Name setter</param>
    /// <param name="state"> Refers to the Task.State setter</param>
    public static void AddTask(string name, States state)
    {
        var task = new Task { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = name, State = state };
        var result = conn.Insert(task);
        

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This method provides the util for Updating a Task.Name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">Refers to the current Task</param>
    public static void UpdateTaskName(Task x)
    {
        var task = new Task { Id = x.Id , Name = x.Name };
        var result = conn.Update(task);
        
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This method provides the util for Updating a Task.Status
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">Refers to the current Task </param>
    public static void UpdateTaskStatus(Task x)
    {
        var task = new Task { Id = x.Id, State = x.State };
        var result = conn.Update(task);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes a Task by his GUID
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Current Task GUID</param>
    public static void DeleteTask(Guid id)
    {
        conn.Delete<Task>(id);
    }
}
```

I get an error

> SQLiteException: Could not open database file: C:\Users\Gabriele Toffnin\Documents\MyData.db (CannotOpen)

I don't know how to resolve because if I specify the same exact things in a non-UWP project, I'm able to make it work.

I'm actually calling the `CreateDB` from here

```
public MainPageView()
{
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainPageViewModel();
        DatabaseTools.CreateDB();
}
```

Comment: UWP App has restricted access to the files, so you may need to check it

Comment: Try just creating a file in this folder from the app, maybe there are some access issues.